# How can I get a robot PoseWithCovarianceStamped from gmapping?

Tags: navigation, ros-indigo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am already simulating with gazebo and trying to create a map with gmappin and I need to get the robot PoseWithCovarianceStamped from the odom and tfs, which gmapping gives. Any idea? Thanks for helping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283210/how-can-i-get-a-robot-posewithcovariancestamped-from-gmapping?/) by [roberto3](https://answers.ros.org/users/33776/roberto3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIR, it is not possible to get something related to uncertainty from tf. So the only point I see (besides changing the source code of `gmapping` itself) is to subscribe to the  `~entropy` topic of  `gmapping` and reason a bit about that. To quote the wiki:

> ~entropy (std_msgs/Float64) Estimate of the entropy of the distribution over the robot's pose (a higher value indicates greater uncertainty). New in 1.1.0.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roberto3](https://answers.ros.org/users/33776/roberto3/) on 2018-02-21**:
Thanks but I need a type PoseWithCovarianceStamped so I need to get the covariance from entropy and the pose from odom but I don't know  how to do it.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-21**:
Entropy and the Covariance Matrix [are related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Entropy). However, it is not possible to retrieve the covariance Matrix from the entropy, afaik. So if you really require PoseWithCovarianceStamped, you'll have to change the code, imo.